# Bootstrap datepicker always opening on the top

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker in a page. The page has a fixed navbar menu. So I have added a `margin-top of 50 + height of the navbar` to a parent div of the datepicker. Now the issue is that the datepicker is always opening on the top. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: erm, use `<input type="date">` instead? I literally hate any js date picker...

Comment: can you try setting position while setting up datepicker?
var options={
            orientation: 'bottom'
        };

Comment: @MohammadHani   It still opens on top.

Comment: is there any space available at bottom of that div? like this usually happens if there's no threshold at the bottom. Can you share any stackblitz or somewhere so that I can look further.